# Getting latest data from kafka consumer

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I am using kafka with my scala application. My code is as follows.

```
object KafkaConsumerSubscribeApp extends App {

  val props:Properties = new Properties()
  props.put("group.id", "test")
  props.put("bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092")
  props.put("key.deserializer",
      "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer") 
  Props.put("value.deserializer",
      "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
props.put("group.id", "consumer-group")
 val consumer: KafkaConsumer[String, String] = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)
    consumer.subscribe(util.Collections.singletonList(topic))
    val record = consumer.poll(5000).asScala.toList.map(_.value())

}
```

This gives me list of values. But I just want the value from the latest offset. I tried searching some examples online but didn't got how to do it. How  I can get the value from the latest offset?

Comment: `props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest")`

Comment: putting this as latest giving me an empty list

Comment: you will get values, when you insert data into Kafka topic after zou started zour job. Or did I misinterpret your question and you actually want to read only the one value from the latest offset?

Comment: yes I only want to read values from latest offset

Comment: I already have data in my kafka topic

Answer (score 0):

The following property will set the offset value to latest. (You will start reading those values that will come to your topic only after your consumer is up and running).

```
props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
```